# Why am I getting DbContext Has Changed exception when using NUnit?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit, dbcontext

I'm using Entity Framework 5 in my project. And I wanted to test some new funcionalities.

What happened is that eventhough my db is UPDATED, (when I add a migration it does not add anything else) and eventhough if I run my project it runs just fine. When I try to test the project with NUNIT I get this exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException : The model backing the 'DbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database`

Has any of you have this problem? If so how can I solve it?

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but maybe your unit test project has its own config file pointing to a non-migrated database?

Comment: Yes It does have a config file! But it has exactly the same connection string than the Main Project one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, my original answer got deleted, guess because it wasn't really an answer as much as a statement that I had the same problem. At this point I have found an answer of sorts, so maybe this one will pass muster.

Of course, I only assume we are having the same issue, but it seems pretty likely since the symptoms are exactly the same. What I discovered is the connection string for my repository was not getting set correctly even though I had set it up "correctly" in a config file using the MyTestProject.dll.config naming convention. Seems like NUnit isn't using the connection string from the config for some reason.

I've set up a temporary solution where I use a different constructor that forces the correct connection string for my repository when creating it for NUnit. Easy to implement this since I'm using DI to create the repository and just need to ask the factory for a different flavor when testing. Working now to figure out why NUnit doesn't use the config file as it seems like it should.

Maybe not a complete answer, but at least this solution got me back to where I can test... We'll see if this one gets deleted.